# How to link html page within several folder

Tags: html

I have some menu named as Home | Service | About us | Contact Us | . The index.html page along with Home menu which is placed in Html folder.Service.html , About.html ,contact.html every page is in separate folder named as service,about,contact which are in Html folder.I have to link every menu with one another.

Answer (score 1):

`copy path` to each file and place it in respective `href` and you are done.

for more info read this:http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/links.html

Comment: Thanks...I can go From Home Menu to Other but I can't go from Service menu to about us menu or About us to service Menu...

Comment: the easy way will be to add a link for about us on service menu and a service link on about menu.and you can always go to home and from there you can go to service or about.